# Saving all incoming messages into a database with Postfix?

Tags: postfix, postgresql

Is there some plugin for Postfix that can allow you to save all incoming messages into a relational database (PostgreSQL)?

Comment: That's not strictly speaking postfix' job. Postfix is an MTA -- Mail Transfer Agent, which makes sure mail gets sent where it should be. For delivering the messages into local mailboxes, it talks to an MDA -- Mail Delivery Agent. There are several that speak SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this product, it's open source and it's called [dbmail](http://www.dbmail.org/).

Based on it's description it sounds like exactly what you want:

> DBMail is an open-source project that enables storage of mail messages
>   in a relational database. Currently MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, and
>   SQLite can be used as storage backends.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in "not only postfix" solutions then you may consider using milters.

- [List of arrchiving milters](https://www.milter.org/milters/archiving/alphabetical/1)
- [MailArchiver milter](https://www.milter.org/milter/61) with MySQL support.

You may consider using [MIMEDefang milter](http://mimedefang.org/) if you plan to use milters also for anti-spam and anti-virus checks.